# "SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER" when use AWS SES SMTP server in GCP Composer Airflow

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, smtp, airflow, amazon-ses

I am using GCP Composer (Airflow) to run some scheduled tasks. And using AWS SES SMTP server to send notification email.

According to GCP Composer's document,
`https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/secret-manager#configuring_your_environment_with` and `https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/configure-email#configure_third-party_smtp_services`, I set the Airflow configuration overrides as below

```
secrets
    backend airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend

smtp
    smtp_port 587
    smtp_mail_from ...
    smtp_host email-smtp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
    smtp_starttls True
    smtp_password_secret smtp-password
    smtp_ssl True
    smtp_user ...
email
    email_backend airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp
```

Airflow has an error when send out the email:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1476, in email_aler
    send_email(self.task.email, subject, html_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/email.py", line 62, in send_emai
    mime_subtype=mime_subtype, mime_charset=mime_charset, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/email.py", line 108, in send_email_smt
    send_MIME_email(smtp_mail_from, recipients, msg, dryrun
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/email.py", line 127, in send_MIME_emai
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT) if SMTP_SSL else smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 1031, in __init_
    source_address
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init_
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connec
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 1039, in _get_socke
    server_hostname=self._host
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socke
    _context=self, _session=session
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init_
    self.do_handshake(
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshak
    self._sslobj.do_handshake(
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshak
    self._sslobj.do_handshake(
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:852
```

How to solve this WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER error?

Answer (score 1):

The AWS SES SMTP has problem when enable SSL on port 587. It need to disable SSL to work on port 587.

Just set `smtp_ssl` to `False` in Airflow's configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions (implement only one):

1. Change **smtp_port to 465**.
2. Change **smtp_ssl True** to **smtp_starttls True** and leave the port at 587.

AWS SES port 587 starts unencrypted and then enables encryption via the STARTTLS command.

AWS SES port 465 starts encrypted and is a best practice.

[Cloud Composer Configure third-party SMTP services](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/configure-email#configure_third-party_smtp_services)

[Connecting to an Amazon SES SMTP endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html)